# Incomprehensible part of the code arp array, pointers and memory allocation (Windows IP functions)

Tags: c++, pointers, winapi, memory, allocation

I wrote some code (with mdsm manual help of course), which can add new record in arp table. But I have problem with understand couple lines of code. I marked these lines between start and stop marks. I don't know how excatly this parts of code works. Event if I remove marked paragraph and replace with

```
GetIpAddrTable(pIpAddrtable, &dwSize, 0)
GetIpAddrTable(pIpAddrtable, &dwSize, 0)
```

program runs "correctly" but something must be wrong, and I want to understand what and why? I think it has to do with memory allocation.

```
#ifndef WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#endif


#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2ipdef.h>
#include <iphlpapi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

#pragma comment(lib, "iphlpapi.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
using namespace std;


int main()
{
ULONG ulOutBufLen;
DWORD dwRetVal;

PIP_ADAPTER_INFO pAdapterInfo;

ulOutBufLen = sizeof(IP_ADAPTER_INFO);

pAdapterInfo = (IP_ADAPTER_INFO *) malloc( sizeof(IP_ADAPTER_INFO) );
ulOutBufLen = sizeof(IP_ADAPTER_INFO);

if (GetAdaptersInfo( pAdapterInfo, &ulOutBufLen) != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
    free (pAdapterInfo);
    pAdapterInfo = (IP_ADAPTER_INFO *) malloc ( ulOutBufLen );
}

if ((dwRetVal = GetAdaptersInfo( pAdapterInfo, &ulOutBufLen)) != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
    printf("GetAdaptersInfo call failed with %d\n", dwRetVal);
}


PMIB_IPADDRTABLE pIpAddrtable;
DWORD dwSize = 0;
DWORD dwRetVal2 = 0;
IN_ADDR IPAddr;


free(pIpAddrtable);
pIpAddrtable = (MIB_IPADDRTABLE *) malloc(dwSize*2);




PIP_ADAPTER_INFO pAdapter = pAdapterInfo;

PMIB_IPNETROW pArpEntry;

DWORD ip = inet_addr("182.221.231.1");



//start
if (pIpAddrtable)
{
    if (GetIpAddrTable(pIpAddrtable, &dwSize, 0) == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)
    {
        free(pIpAddrtable);
        cout <<"Za mała ilosc pamięci";
    }

    if (pIpAddrtable == NULL) {
            printf("Memory allocation failed for GetIpAddrTable\n");
            exit(1);
        }

    if (dwRetVal2 = GetIpAddrTable(pIpAddrtable, &dwSize, 0) != NO_ERROR)
    {
        printf("Mamy error %s", dwRetVal2);
    }
}



//stop
pArpEntry->dwIndex = pIpAddrtable->table[0].dwIndex;
pArpEntry->dwPhysAddrLen = 6;
pArpEntry->bPhysAddr[0] = '0x01';
pArpEntry->bPhysAddr[1] = '0xb2';
pArpEntry->bPhysAddr[2] = '0xd3';
pArpEntry->bPhysAddr[3] = '0xd4';
pArpEntry->bPhysAddr[4] = '0x05';
pArpEntry->bPhysAddr[5] = '0x16';
pArpEntry->dwType = MIB_IPNET_TYPE_STATIC;
pArpEntry->dwAddr = ip;

if (CreateIpNetEntry(pArpEntry) == ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED)
{
    cout <<"Dostęp zabroniony ";
}
while (pAdapter)
{
    printf(TEXT("Nazwa adaptera: %s \n"), pAdapter->AdapterName);
    printf("Adres adaptera: %s \n", pAdapter->IpAddressList.IpAddress.String);
    printf("Maska: %s \n ", pAdapter->IpAddressList.IpMask.String);
    printf("Opis:  %s \n ", pAdapter->Description);
    printf("Serwer DHCP %s \n ", pAdapter->DhcpServer.IpAddress.String);
    printf("Indeks: %5d \n ", pAdapter->Index);

    cout <<endl;
    pAdapter = pAdapter->Next;
}




    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1) `pArpEntry` is uninitialized.  2) You check for errors when calling the API functions, but in at least two cases your code keeps going as if there are no errors.  3) You're using `C++`, not `C`.  You could improve it by eliminating all of the dynamic memory allocation using `malloc` and use `std::vector<char>` with a `reinterpret_cast` to cast to the correct pointer type.

Answer (score 2):

As my comments suggested, instead of taking verbatim the `C` implementation of the sample, you should adjust it so that it doesn't use raw memory allocation using `malloc`, and instead used `std::vector`.

In addition, there are several errors in your sample, the major one being that you are using an uninitialized `pArpEntry` pointer.  I will address this later.

Here is a proper sample that works correctly and uses no dynamic memory allocation.

```
#ifndef WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#endif

#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2ipdef.h>
#include <iphlpapi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#pragma comment(lib, "iphlpapi.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ULONG ulOutBufLen;
    DWORD dwRetVal;
    ulOutBufLen = 0;

    // create a vector we will use for the PIP_ADAPTER_INFO data
    std::vector<char> adapterInfo;

    // call the INET API function with the vector contents serving
    // as the PIP_ADAPTER_INFO
    if (GetAdaptersInfo(reinterpret_cast<PIP_ADAPTER_INFO>(adapterInfo.data()), &ulOutBufLen) == ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW) 
        // resize the buffer 
        adapterInfo.resize(ulOutBufLen);
```

Take note of the last two lines of code.  The `GetAdaptersInfo` function is first called with a buffer size of 0.  This will fail with an `ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW` error (hopefully).  Once it does do this, we resize the `adapterInfo` vector to the size of the `ulOutBufLen`, not by using `malloc`, but by merely calling the `std::vector::resize` function.  No dynamic memory allocation, no pointers, etc.

Note that we had to `reinterpret_cast` the pointer in the API call, since that is the pointer type the call is asking for.

Going on:

```
    if ((dwRetVal = GetAdaptersInfo(reinterpret_cast<PIP_ADAPTER_INFO>(adapterInfo.data()), &ulOutBufLen) != ERROR_SUCCESS))
    {
        std::cout << "GetAdaptersInfo call failed with " << dwRetVal;
        return -1;
    }

    PIP_ADAPTER_INFO pAdapter = reinterpret_cast<PIP_ADAPTER_INFO>(adapterInfo.data());
```

We stop the program if after resizing, we get an error.  If successful, we make our code a little simpler by assigning the address of the adapter information to `pAdapter` by `reinterpret_cast` on the returned adapter information.

Going on:

```
    DWORD dwSize = 0;
    DWORD dwRetVal2 = 0;
    std::vector<char> pIpAddrtable;

    if (GetIpAddrTable(reinterpret_cast<PMIB_IPADDRTABLE>(pIpAddrtable.data()), &dwSize, 0) == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)
    {
        pIpAddrtable.resize(dwSize);
        if (dwRetVal2 = GetIpAddrTable(reinterpret_cast<PMIB_IPADDRTABLE>(pIpAddrtable.data()), &dwSize, 0) != NO_ERROR)
        {
            std::cout << "Many error " << dwRetVal2;
            return -1;
        }
    }
```

This is basically the same pattern as the `PIP_ADAPTER_INFO` code previously.  We create a vector, call the IP function to get the size, resize the vector with the returned size.

Going on:

```
    MIB_IPNETROW arpEntry;
    if (CreateIpNetEntry(&arpEntry) == ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED)
    {
        cout << "Access denied\n";
    }
```

We do not need to allocate anything in the call to `CreateIpNetEntry`.  All we need to do is pass the address of an existing `MIB_IONETROW` instance.  This eliminates the uninitialized pointer error you had in your original code.

Going on:

```
    PMIB_IPADDRTABLE theTable = reinterpret_cast<PMIB_IPADDRTABLE>(pIpAddrtable.data());
    arpEntry.dwIndex = theTable->table[0].dwIndex;
    arpEntry.dwPhysAddrLen = 6;
    arpEntry.bPhysAddr[0] = 0x01;
    arpEntry.bPhysAddr[1] = 0xb2;
    arpEntry.bPhysAddr[2] = 0xd3;
    arpEntry.bPhysAddr[3] = 0xd4;
    arpEntry.bPhysAddr[4] = 0x05;
    arpEntry.bPhysAddr[5] = 0x16;
    arpEntry.dwType = MIB_IPNET_TYPE_STATIC;
    arpEntry.dwAddr = ip;
```

We get a pointer to the `PMIB_ADDRTABLE` by `reinterpret_cast`-ing the data in the `pIpAddrtable` vector (we call the pointer `theTable`).

Going on:

```
    while (pAdapter)
    {
        std::cout << pAdapter->AdapterName << "\n";
        std::cout << pAdapter->IpAddressList.IpAddress.String << "\n";
        std::cout << pAdapter->IpAddressList.IpMask.String << "\n";
        std::cout << pAdapter->Description << "\n";
        std::cout << pAdapter->DhcpServer.IpAddress.String << "\n";
        std::cout << pAdapter->Index << "\n";
        std::cout << endl;
        pAdapter = pAdapter->Next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This outputs the adapter information.

Again, the magic into why this works is that we used `std::vector<char>` and resized the vector whenever the Windows IP function returns to us the correct buffer size.  This eliminates the usage of `malloc`, and instead we simply use `std::vector::resize`.

The other thing we need to do is to use `reinterpret_cast`, since the API functions actually need the correct pointer type for the code to compile correctly.  It's ugly, but that's how the `C` interface was coded, so the `C++` equivalent needed to do the same thing.

There are no calls to `malloc`, no calls to `free`, no pointers to deal with (except the `reinterpret_cast`'s), no memory leaks.

Here is the complete implementation using the on-line Visual Studio 2015 compiler:

[Complete Example](http://rextester.com/CCAL86820)

Comment: So why in MSD they still use malloc? And I thank you so much because you wrote all so clearly that I can understand what it going on this code :)

Comment: The sample from MSDN was written for the `C` compiler, not C++.  With `C`, you have little choice but to use `malloc` or similar function.